# How to map through a json object that is stored in a react component not coming from an api?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, typescript

I have a file inside my react project, glossaryItems.json.  The file looks like this:

```
        {
            "glossary": [
                {
                    "name": "Constant",
                    "pageNumber": "33",
                    "definition": "A value that cannot change while the program is running.",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Debugging",
                    "pageNumber": "45",
                    "definition": "The process of finding and reducing the number of defects in a computer program.",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Algorithm",
                    "pageNumber": "4",
                    "definition": "A strictly defined finite sequence of well-defined statements that provides the solution to a problem."
                }
            ]
        }
```

I have another file, glossaryPage.tsx where I would like to display each glossary item within a tab.  I am not sure how to access the json file in order to use it within the tsx file.  I ended up changing the  json file to a .ts file and exported it as so:

```
export const glossaryItems =
[
{
            "glossary": [
                {
                    "name": "Constant",
                    "pageNumber": "33",
                    "definition": "A value that cannot change while the program is running.",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Debugging",
                    "pageNumber": "45",
                    "definition": "The process of finding and reducing the number of defects in a computer program.",
                },
                {
                    "name": "Algorithm",
                    "pageNumber": "4",
                    "definition": "A strictly defined finite sequence of well-defined statements that provides the solution to a problem."
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

And then imported it inside glossaryPage.tsx.  I want to be able to get the each part of the json separately to be able to use it inside the tabs.  So I would have one tab labeled "Constant", a second tab, "Debugging", a third tab "Algorithm"  and under each tab display that information such as pagenumber and definition that applies to that tab. I tried mapping over just the glossary but was unable to.  I had to map over the glossaryItems.

```
const GlossaryPage = () => {
 const terms = glossaryItems.map(({glossary}, key) => (
          <div key={key}>
            {glossary.map(({name, pageNumber, definition}, key) => (
              <div key={key}> 
              <p>{name}</p>
              </div>
              ))}
            </div> 
          ))
  return ( 
<SprkTabsPanel
    isDefaultActive
    tabBtnChildren={terms[0]} //this is where the terms are printing out on the tab
    tabBtnAnalyticsString="tab-1"
    tabBtnDataId="tab-1"
  >
  
  </SprkTabsPanel>
```

I thought that by indexing the terms it would give me the term at that index but it gives me all of the terms.  This is what it looks like: [image]

How can I get the individual values of the object?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can import directly from a `.json` file as long as you have `"resolveJsonModule": true` in your `tsconfig`.  I'll have to take a closer look to see why your mapping is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Importing JSON

In order to import a `.json` file, you simply need to enable support in your `tsconfig.json` file.  Set `"resolveJsonModule": true` inside the `compilerOptions` property.  Now you can import the data from the JSON file as a default import.

[Docs: Resolve JSON Module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule)

#### Mapping Your Object

I had a look at [the documentation](https://react.sparkdesignsystem.com/?path=/docs/components-tabs--default-story) for the Spark Design system and it seems like you need to create a separate `SprkTabsPanel` component for each tab.  All of the individual tab panels go inside of one `SprkTabs` component.

```
import React from "react";
import { SprkTabs, SprkTabsPanel } from "@sparkdesignsystem/spark-react";
import glossaryItems from "./glossaryItems.json";

const GlossaryPage = () => {
  return (
    <SprkTabs idString="glossary-tabs">
      {glossaryItems.glossary.map(({ name, pageNumber, definition }, key) => (
        <SprkTabsPanel tabBtnChildren={name} key={key}>
          <p>{definition}</p>
          <p>Page Number: {pageNumber}</p>
        </SprkTabsPanel>
      ))}
    </SprkTabs>
  );
};

export default GlossaryPage;
```

Comment: thank you for your help.  I am getting an error under glossary when trying to do glossaryItems.glossary.map.  It says Property 'glossary' does not exist on type '{const: {glossary: {name: string; pageNumber: string; definition: string; }[]; }[];}'

Comment: So based on the error your JSON has a property “const” with a property “glossary” under it.  Get rid of that “const”.  Also there’s two levels of arrays?  Do you have a single glossary or multiple glossaries?  The JSON I used was a copy and paste of the first block in your post where it’s an object with a property “glossary” which is an array.  I don’t know why in your second one you put the glossary inside of an array.

Comment: thank you for your quick response!  I was just coming back to delete my comment and mark your solution as correct.  I must not have saved all my files before running and it was taking the glossary from how I had it in the .ts file instead of the .json